# Multiple-entry Italian Schengen visa, can I go to Switzerland/Austria for a weekend?

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a multiple-entry Italian Schengen visa that will last a couple of months. Within this period, I want to go to Switzerland for a weekend, and to Austria for another weekend. Can I just get on a train and arrive there? Or do I need to do some paperwork, request another visa, or something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just go on a train and arrive there.

A Schengen visa allows you to travel anywhere in the Schengen region. It should be even less trouble with a multiple-entry visa, where it is *expected* that you will use it for trips in addition to the one you originally applied for.

The Schengen construction is currently creaking a bit under the weight of the refugee/migrant situation, and there's been some talk of "suspending Shchengen" that may sound alarming. But this is just a matter of introducing systematic *border checks* at some of the internal borders, and does *not* involve changing the rules for who is *allowed* to go where. There's no talk of changing how Schengen *visas* work anywhere in the near future, much less the validity of already issued ones. You might experience having to show your passport/visa when you cross the Italy/Austria border -- but since your visa is actually in order, that should not be a problem for you.

Comment: Might want to note the (rare but existing) limited territorial valididty Schengen visas.

Comment: @CMaster care to elaborate?

Comment: @becko: It is _possible_ for states to issue short-term visas that are only valid for their own territory but not for the rest of the Schengen area. This is supposed to be an exceptional case, only used if the issuing state knows that you're not wanted in one of the other states (in which case they'd still be more likely simply to reject you). If your visa is type C and says "stati Schengen" in the "valid for" field, you're good.

Comment: There's also special cases for citizens of states with limited recognition. Eg. someone with a Kosovan passport can't go to Spain: travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53801/can-i-travel-to-spain-with-kosovo-passport/